# Syntax for extracting pointer from container back()

Tags: c++

Is this acceptable syntax? It looks messy which tends to make me think it is not so elegant:

`cdata.lastAnimation=&(this->animations.back());`

`cdata.lastAnimation` is a pointer, but since `back()` returns a reference, not a pointer, I need to get the address?

You might be thinking, why not just make `cdata.lastAnimation` a reference instead of a pointer? Because `cdata` is a POD `struct` and references cannot be assigned, unlike pointers, which can. (perhaps one of the few examples of why a pointer is better in some cases than a reference).

Comment: Note that depending on the container the pointer so obtained might become invalidated quite easily (i.e. if the container is a vector, it can become invalidated with the next `push_back`...)

Comment: Thanks @DavidRodríguez-dribeas. I am actually using `deque`s and `lists` and have read up on the iterator validity after various operations, but you offer a good reminder for other readers of this question.

Comment: For lists you are safe, for `deque` only if there are no insertions/deletions anywhere other than the two ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that will work fine, though it can probably (very seldom not) be shortened to this:

```
cdata.lastAnimation = &animations.back();
```

That seems a little bit better to me at least.